What lion looking creature is on the mat hanging on the wall outside of Professor Fig's classroom?
If you exit Professor Fig's classroom and look to your right, there's a hanging mat on the wall that has some kind of lion mixed with a bird creature on it:

What creature is this?

My initial guess was gryphon, because of the wings, which could indicate part eagle. Though usually the head is a gryphon instead of a lion. I also came across 'Gwazi - A creature with the head of a tiger and the body of a lion.', but I don't recall any references in the Hogwarts universe.
